# MQTT with IOT: one MQTTCLIENT for each IoT device or message

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I am designing the MQTT protocol with mosquitto and have a few questions:

1. Should I create a mqttclient for each IoT device or message?
2. Is there any sample code to create one mqttclient for each IoT device?
3. Do I need to use MqttAyncClient or MqttClient?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create one client and reuse it for each message you want to publish
2. Have you checked the source paho?
3. That entirely depends on your application, do you need synchronous or asynchronous message publishing?